# kernel panic error after recompilation

Tags: debian, kernel, virtualbox

I am completely blocked, but temporarily.
I have an Ubuntu 11.10 in good condition, in this one I installed VirtuelBox.
I installed on VirtuelBox as Ghest Debian Squeeze with Kernel 2.6.32-5-686.
ja 'tried to recompile my kernel to erase all composont driver then I turned on the current configuration of the driver necessary for the operation of Ghest Debian.
Steps for compiling and installing the kernel are:

> ```
> root login
> # nano /etc/apt/sources.list
> # apt-get update
> # apt-get install debconf-utils debhelper dpkg-dev build-essential kernel-package libncurses5-dev
> # uname-r
> 2.6.32-5-686
> # wget http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v2.6/linux-2.6.32.5.tar.bz2
> # tar xvjf linux-2.6.32.5.tar.bz2
> # mv linux-2.6.32.5/ /usr/src/
> # cd /usr/src/linux-2.6.32.5/
> # cp /boot/config-2.6.32-5-686. config
> ### make allnoconfig##
> # make menuconfig
> we selected the penultimate year Load Alternate Configuration File
> you exit the menu while watching
> # make-kpkg - append-to-version "-tango" - initrd buildpackage-us-uc
> the image is now in /usr/src/
> # dpkg-i linux-image-2.6.32.5-tango-tango-2.6.32.5-10.00Custom_i386.deb
> ```
>
> an error when starting the first line from Grub
>   kernel panic not syncing vfs Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block 0 0
>   [image: GRUB]

[image: ERROR]

[image: after recompilation]
lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
ppdev                   4058  0 
lp                      5570  0 
binfmt_misc             4907  1 
fuse                   44268  1 
loop                    9769  0 
snd_intel8x0           19595  1 
snd_ac97_codec         79200  1 snd_intel8x0
ac97_bus                 710  1 snd_ac97_codec
snd_pcm                47226  2 snd_intel8x0,snd_ac97_codec
snd_seq                35463  0 
snd_timer              12270  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd_seq_device          3673  1 snd_seq
parport_pc             15799  0 
parport                22554  3 ppdev,lp,parport_pc
snd                    34423  8 snd_intel8x0,snd_ac97_codec,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_timer,snd_seq_device
psmouse                44809  0 
pcspkr                  1207  0 
serio_raw               2916  0 
ac                      1640  0 
joydev                  6739  0 
evdev                   5609  8 
i2c_piix4               7076  0 
button                  3598  0 
i2c_core               12787  1 i2c_piix4
soundcore               3450  1 snd
snd_page_alloc          5045  2 snd_intel8x0,snd_pcm
ext3                   94396  5 
jbd                    32317  1 ext3
mbcache                 3762  1 ext3
usbhid                 28008  0 
hid                    50909  1 usbhid
sg                     19937  0 
sr_mod                 10770  0 
cdrom                  26487  1 sr_mod
sd_mod                 26005  7 
crc_t10dif              1012  1 sd_mod
ata_generic             2247  0 
ohci_hcd               16999  0 
ata_piix               17736  0 
ahci                   27410  6 
ehci_hcd               28693  0 
thermal                 9206  0 
libata                115869  3 ata_generic,ata_piix,ahci
thermal_sys             9378  1 thermal
usbcore                98969  4 usbhid,ohci_hcd,ehci_hcd
nls_base                4541  1 usbcore
scsi_mod              104853  4 sg,sr_mod,sd_mod,libata
e1000                  77317  0 
root@debian:/boot# 
root@debian:/boot# lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 440FX - 82441FX PMC [Natoma] (rev 02)
00:01.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82371SB PIIX3 ISA [Natoma/Triton II]
00:01.1 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 IDE (rev 01)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: InnoTek Systemberatung GmbH VirtualBox Graphics Adapter
00:03.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82540EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 02)
00:04.0 System peripheral: InnoTek Systemberatung GmbH VirtualBox Guest Service
00:05.0 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation 82801AA AC'97 Audio Controller (rev 01)
00:06.0 USB Controller: Apple Computer Inc. KeyLargo/Intrepid USB
00:07.0 Bridge: Intel Corporation 82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 ACPI (rev 08)
00:0b.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller
00:0d.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 82801HBM/HEM (ICH8M/ICH8M-E) SATA AHCI Controller (rev 02)
root@debian:/boot# 
root@debian:/boot# lscpu
Architecture:          i686
CPU(s):                1
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    1
CPU socket(s):         1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 15
Stepping:              13
CPU MHz:               1983.975
root@debian:/boot#

the file .config is in the link: [.config](http://tmedtcom.unblog.fr/config/)
Help me please

Comment: The commands that you show are clearly not copy-pasted (there are multiple typos; these commands would not have run). While this doesn't matter here because you haven't posted what would be the relevant information (what you removed from the `.config`), it's a bad idea. Always copy-paste commands and error messages, don't retype them.

Answer (score 3):

The message indicates that the kernel could not mount the root filesystem. This can have several causes:

1. The device that the root filesystem is on is not working or took too long to become ready (usually an issue booting from USB or possibly NFS).
2. The bootloader configuration is broken, and the root device passed on the kernel command line is incorrect.
3. The kernel lacks support for one of the features needed to access the root filesystem: one of the necessary drivers is missing. Typically the missing component is the filesystem driver or the block device driver (e.g. SATA chipset); also check that you've included the necessary RAID methods, LVM, encryption, etc.
4. A necessary driver is compiled as a module, but not included in the initramfs or initrd, or you are booting without an initramfs or initrd. If you recompile the kernel and need a module to access the root filesystem, be sure to regenerate the initramfs/initrd.

Given that you've just recompiled a kernel, #3 is the most likely explanation. You've missed some necessary driver in your kernel configuration.

Check your `.config` carefully. There's something missing in there. Start with the existing `.config` that's working now (as you did, going by the commands you posted) and don't remove stuff if you aren't sure that it isn't used.

Comment: I just want to compile the kernel, leaving all the components and I want to leave just the drivers needed to operate the hardware of the machine Ghest (Debian) under VirtuelBox.
what should I do in the compilation:
# make allnoconfig => is that this command is just to remove all the drivers?
in the menuconfig is that when I did: Load Alternate Configuration File is only to load drivers necessary

Comment: Go back into your working kernel and do an `lsmod` - also check the output of `lspci` and `lscpu`.  `lsmod` will tell you what modules have been loaded and can give you clues as to what you should build into your kernel.  You can search in `make menuconfig` by module name if you are unsure of what something is (I am a good percentage of the time).

Comment: @ultrasawblade Actually, support for the root filesystem can be compiled as a module, as long as this module is included in the initramfs (since tmedtcom is using the Debian kernel tools, he should have a matching initramfs). Support for the initramfs must be included in the kernel proper.

Comment: @tmedtcom You clearly removed too many drivers. Since you didn't post your `.config`, we can't tell what you removed. Note that even if you do post your `.config`, it's possible that no one will want to go through the hundreds of lines to find what's missing. Really, if you want to remove drivers, it's up to you to check that they are not needed.

Comment: donc qu'est ce que je dois faire?
vous donner le contenue du fichier .config ou le resultat des commandes lsmod  lspci lscpu?
avez vous une idée?

Comment: @tmedtcom The contents of `.config` would help. But I'm not sure that anyone will bother looking for the missing entry. Again, *you* need to make sure you aren't removing anything that you need. P.S. this is an international forum, please stick to English.

Comment: sorry to write in French, I forgot.
So I will try to recompile the kernel. and I return